# Selenium insert number into table

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I want to fill first row in web page table with selenium webdriver. Into the table I need to insert number. Is there any way how to insert number with selenium webdriver into table?

I have this code so far:

```
row = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]')

row.click()
time.sleep(2)
row.send_keys("100")
```

I'm getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\N\PycharmProjects\pokus\venv\pokus.py", line 29, in <module>
    row.send_keys("100")
  File "C:\Users\N\PycharmProjects\pokus\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\N\PycharmProjects\pokus\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\N\PycharmProjects\pokus\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\N\PycharmProjects\pokus\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.125)


Process finished with exit code 1
```